# How can I tell to the rule I am writing that the value of region field is the value coming from webform data?

Tags: rules, webforms

I successfully created a webform using the [Webform](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform) module.

Using [Webform Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_rules) I can create a new entity of type user and I fill the requested fields using, for example, `[data:name-value-raw]` for name, `[data:surname-value-raw]` for surname, etc...

This is very easy for text fields but I have troubles with text list fields, in my custom user fields I have two text-list fields (region list and country list), I set the same list in the webform.

In the Rules Action "Create a new entity" the Rules UI tells me to set a value for these fields but I'm forced to choose from a value in the list.

[image]

If I <kbd>Switch to data selection</kbd> I can't find submitted values, so how can I tell to the rule I am writing that the value of region field is the value coming from Webform data?

Answer (score 0):

> If I switch to data selection I can't find submitted values, so how can I tell to the rule I am writing that the value of region field is the value coming from webform data?

You can use a technique similar to what is described in [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191977/39516) to "[How to do a data comparison to submitted webform data when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/191953/39516)". For short:

- Add an extra Rules Action to `Add a variable` (call it whatever you want), with a value assigned to it equal to your `[data:ComponentFieldName-value-raw]` (with a data type which equals the data type of your Webform component), and with `ComponentFieldName` whatever you're using for that region field in your Webform).
- In your subsequent Rules Actions you can refer to the value of this variable you just added (that's the clue!).

Comment: Thank you for your reply but if you read better my question I still use the webform fields to populate entity values, my problem is on list fields that I can't set with my custom default value...

Comment: The question is simple: how to set the value of "Region" that is a TEXT LIST, I repeat, a TEXT LIST field.
I can set what I want to TEXT fields but not with TEXT LIST fileds.

Comment: Please, read everything I wrote, I don't need a loop to create a single entity user from a webform submission. I invite you to read WELL what I wrote...

Comment: @SmurfXXX can you try with the technique I described in my updated answer?