# How to add a rule condition from select-list in a webform

Tags: 7, rules, webforms, emails

This an export of my rule

```
{ "rules_webform_to_simplenews" : {
    "LABEL" : "Webform to simplenews",
    "PLUGIN" : "reaction rule",
    "OWNER" : "rules",
    "REQUIRES" : [ "webform_rules", "rules", "simplenews_rules" ],
    "ON" : { "webform_rules_submit" : [] },
    "IF" : [
      { "webform_has_id" : {
          "form_id" : "webform-client-form-113",
          "selected_webform" : { "value" : {
              "webform-client-form-27" : "webform-client-form-27",
              "webform-client-form-113" : "webform-client-form-113"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ],
    "DO" : [
      { "simplenews_rules_action_subscribe" : { "mail" : "[data:e_mail-value]", "tid" : "211", "confirmation" : "2" } }
    ]
  }
}
```

When a webform is submitted, the e-mailadres is added to the newsletter-subscriptions. 
But there should be an extra condition that the submitter agrees the subscribing by checking a select-option on the webform.

when i use the data-selector *data:newsletter-value* or *data:newsletter-key* for parmeter, it is refused.

Comment: what do you mean by "it is refused"? what error message do you get?

Comment: i' having the next-error: "Data selector data:newsletter-value for parameter data is invalid."

Comment: does it show this data selector as available in the replacement patterns section in the rule?

Comment: no, it isn't in the patterns

Comment: any feedback about my answer?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a technique similar to what is described in [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191977/39516) to "[How to do a data comparison to submitted webform data when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/191953/39516)". For short:

- Add an extra Rules Action to `Add a variable`, with a value assigned to it equal to your `[data:newsletter-value-raw]` (assuming `newsletter` is the form component containing your select-option) and with a data type which equals the data type of your Webform component. In your subsequent Rules Actions you can refer to the value of this variable you just added (that's the clue!).
- Use the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module to perform a data comparison. In this case to check the value of your select-option. If so, and only then, perform your Rules Action to add the email address as a subscriber.

PS: Instead of using the [Conditional Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_conditional) module, you could also rework the Rules Action to performing Rules Components (in which you add the appropriate Rules Conditions), so that you don't need this extra module. For more details on that, refer to the answer to "[What's the alternative to using the Conditional Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/245049/39516)".