# Webform Rules - Create a Drupal User

Tags: 7, users, civicrm, webforms

I'm using Webforms (*via the Webform module*) and using Rules (with the *Rules module* and the *Webform Rules module*)... as a side note, I'm also using CiviCRM although I don't think that is has an impact of the issue I am having...

When using Rules I can specify an action to take place on a given event - in my case when a particular webform is submitted.  **When webform 'a' is submitted I want a Drupal user to be created...**

If I use the action 'create entity' and specify that the entity to be created is of type 'User' then **if I statically enter the value** for the username and the e-mail address the Drupal **account is created**.

However, if I try to tell the action creation process to **use the value entered in the webform** as the username and the e-mail address ( e.g. [data:{component}-value] where {component} is substituted for the machine name of the field in question ) for the intended Drupal account, **no Drupal account is created**.  Does anyone know why this is the case and what the solution for this is?

**Side note:** I know the value used in [data:{component}-value] is correct as I added an action saying output a message and added the data field to the message and it shows the correct details (e.g those entered in the webform)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a technique similar to what is described in [my answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/191977/39516) to "[How to do a data comparison to submitted webform data when using the Rules module?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/q/191953/39516)". For short:

- Add an extra Rules Action to `Add a variable`, with a value assigned to it equal to your `[data:ComponentFieldName-value-raw]` (and with a data type which equals the data type of your Webform component). Looks like you need 2 variables though: 1 for the username, one for the eMail ID.
- In your subsequent Rules Actions you can refer to the value of these variables you just added (that's the clue!).